INFO CODE = -1 when using zfeast_hcsrev in intel mkl
I 'm trying to solve eigenvalues using zfeast_hcsrev. I wrote a simple test file and just gave a simple diagonal matrix but I got info code=-1. I compiled with the command "icpx -qmkl=sequential test.cpp"  on wsl2 with mkl version " 2023.1.0". And Here is my test file.
#include "mkl.h"

MKL_INT main(void) {

  char uplo = 'F';
  MKL_INT n = 8;
  double emin = 2.0;
  double emax = 5.0;
  MKL_INT m0 = 5;
  MKL_INT info;
  double epsout;
  MKL_INT loop, m;

  double *e = new double[m0];
  MKL_Complex16 *x = new MKL_Complex16[n * m0];
  double *res = new double[m0];

  MKL_INT rowptr[9] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
  MKL_INT colidx[8] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
  MKL_Complex16 data[8] = {{1.0, 0.0}, {1.9, 0.0}, {3.0, 0.0}, {4.0, 0.0},
                           {5.2, 0.0}, {6.0, 0.0}, {7.0, 0.0}, {8.0, 0.0}};
  MKL_INT fpm[128];
  feastinit(fpm);
  fpm[0] = 1;

  zfeast_hcsrev(&uplo, &n, data, rowptr, colidx, fpm, &epsout, &loop, &emin,
                &emax, &m0, e, x, &m, res, &info);

  return 0;
}

Hope some nice people can tell me where is the bug.
